# jQuery buttons in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery buttons on my page. Whenever I click one of them the Internet Explorer adds an ugly black border because the button is active. When I brows the [jQuery button sample page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/) with IE this border is not visible when I click one of the example buttons.

Why not?? How do they avoid this border? I checked their CSS files but could not find anything...

The only way to disable that border is using a CSS filter (which is not valid CSS):

```
button { filter:chroma(color=#000000); }
```

Maybe there is a better solution to this?

Comment: This is still the case +2 years later :(

Answer (score 0):

Do you have anything else in your CSS that could be causing this?  If it's not appearing on the sample page then there's something in your markup/css/javascript that's causing it.

Try making an isolated sample with just the buttons in and adding all other CSS until you find out what's causing it.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful using this CSS filter. This will cause the side effect in IE8 - bullets inside radio buttons will become invisible. Thus visually would seem that radio buttons do not work thoug they are operating properly.